# get console.timeEnd() to not log all by itself

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to get the amount of time the process took to fully complete. I have this code:

```js
console.log(`Ran ${ran} equations in ${console.timeEnd()}`)
```

but I don't get my expected output, which is:

```
Ran X equations in 33.099ms // eg
```

instead I get

```
default: 33.099ms
Ran X Equations in undefined
```

Note that I didn't give my `console.time()` a label.

How can I achieve my expected output?

Comment: danh's answer is good, but if you want manual control over timing, you can use `const startMs = Date.now();` and later `const durationMs = Date.now() - startMs;`. to get the duration in milliseconds.

Comment: @user2740650 performance is quite a bit faster and more accurate than Date.now()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.timeEnd` doesn't return anything; it's part of the console, as you know. Because `console.timeEnd` counts in milliseconds with decimal places (unlike [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)), the closest thing you'll get is with [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now). We can create a custom time function:

```js
class Time {
  constructor() {
    this.time = performance.now();
  }
  end() {
    return (performance.now() - this.time).toFixed(3); // round number to lower decimal precision, like console.time()
  }
}

const time = new Time();
console.time("Console measurement");

let dummyVar = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  // do some time consuming task
  dummyVar += i;
}

console.log("Custom measurement:", time.end() + "ms");
console.timeEnd("Console measurement");
```

I intentionally returned a number and not a string (with "ms" at the end) so you could use it better. Obviously, if you want to represent the exact output of `console.timeEnd()`, simply append `+ "ms"` to the expression in `Time#end`:

```js
class Time {
  constructor() {
    this.time = performance.now();
  }
  end() {
    return (performance.now() - this.time).toFixed(3) + "ms";
  }
}

const time = new Time();

// dummy example
setTimeout(() => console.log(`Ran X equations in ${time.end()}`), Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
```

Comment: performance is quite a bit faster and more accurate than Date.now()

Answer (score 0):

`console.timeEnd()` returns `undefined`, not what it logs. To get very close to the desired output, label the timer with the descriptive string...

```js
const ran = 4; // you'll need to know ran before starting the timer
const label = `Ran ${ran} equations in`;
console.time(label);
// do some time consuming stuff
alert('wait a sec, then press ok')
console.timeEnd(label);
```